# How to validate whether a ManyToMany relationship exists Django?

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Interest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    interests = models.ManyToManyField(Interest, related_name='person_interests')

    def add_interest(self, interest_pk):
        interest = Interest.objects.get(pk=interest_pk)
        if not interests in self.interests:
            self.interests.add(interest)
```

The above code does not work, but it indicates what I want to do.

In short, I want to validate whether a relation exists or not, if it does not, then I add the relationship. What is the efficient way to do this using django models.

Thanks.

Comment: How you invoke `add_interest` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [`_add_items`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py#L989) function of `ManyRelatedManager`, it already takes care of what you want here:

```
vals = (self.through._default_manager.using(db)
        .values_list(target_field_name, flat=True)
        .filter(**{
            source_field_name: self.related_val[0],
            '%s__in' % target_field_name: new_ids,
        }))
new_ids = new_ids - set(vals)
```

It removes all the `ids` which are already present in the through table. So you don't really need to check anything. You can directly use `add` function:

```
def add_interest(self, interest_pk):
    self.interests.add(interest_pk)
```

And, of course it will throw error if the `interest_pk` doesn't exist yet because that's the basic requirement of `add` function.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
def add_interest(self, interest_pk):
    interest = Interest.objects.get(pk=interest_pk)
    if interest not in self.interests.all():
        self.interests.add(interest)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check if this helps.

```
person = Person.objects.filter(name = 'something):
if person.count() > 0:
   interests = person[0].interests.all()
   if interests.count() > 0:
        ###DO something..
```

#### In this case,

```
def add_interest(self, interest_pk):
    interests = self.interests.all()
    if interests.count():
           ### Add
```